# ¿Como acceder a un archivo en el directorio bin de mi servicio WCF?

Tags: c#, iis, wcf

Tengo un servicio [wcf](/questions/tagged/wcf) que se encarga de enviar correos con una plantilla `html` como base, el cual lo intento leer como muestro más abajo, hasta ahora no puedo leerlo. Mi servicio está hosteado en *IIS 7.5*

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es lo siguiente:

```
string path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/bin/Template/file.html");

text = File.ReadAllText(@path);
```

Pero `path` queda como `null`

¿Cómo podría acceder a ese archivo `html` ?

---

En otro intento traté de utilizar lo siguiente pero con el mismo resultado:

```
path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
```

Comment: Deberías revisar si efectivamente el archivo existe en la ruta; en caso de ser así, revisa si el directorio tiene permisos de lectura. Revisa esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/753291/4092887).

Comment: Estoy seguro de que existe y tengo permisos, en realidad el usuario con el que corre en el pool de aplicaciones de IIS tiene permisos así que no debería haber problemas.

Comment: Alan, prueba usando `Path.GetDirectoryName(ruta_archivo)`. _esta es otra sugerencia de prueba_, cambia la ruta y coloca la ruta absoluta. Es todo lo que se me ocurre, pero espero que otros usuarios te brinden mas ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para recuperar la carpeta donde se está ejecutando tu servicio deberias usar Reflection de esta forma

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
```

Comment: Te dí +1 porque obtengo el path pero no me  está gustando como queda, `file://C://....`

Comment: @Alan, respecto a tu comentario, ¿cómo deseas que quede el resultado?

Comment: Perdón me demoré en responder, quería ver si con las rutas relativas podía acceder pero me quedo con tu respuesta que funciona. Gracias.